# Absolute Value of a function differentiable

Tags: calculus, integration

If $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $f(x_0) \neq 0$, is $|f|$ differentiable at $x_0$?

I know that I have to show that the limit exists but I'm not sure of what steps to take after
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{|f(x_n)|-|f(x_0)|}{x_n-x_0}$$

Comment: It suffices to observe that $x \mapsto |x|$ is differentiable except for the point zero. And that's easy bc for any $x_0>0$ it is equal to the identity function on a nbhd of $x_0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f(x_0)>0$, then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)>0$ for every $x\in(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ so taking a sequence $(x_n)_n$ contained in $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ and converging to $x_0$ you obtain:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|f(x_n)|-|f(x_0)|}{x_n-x_0}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x_n)-f(x_0)}{x_n-x_0}=f'(x_0)
$$
and the last limit exists since $f(x)$ is derivable in $x_0$.
Suppose now $f(x_0)<0$, then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)<0$ for every $x\in(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ so taking a sequence $(x_n)_n$ contained in $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ and converging to $x_0$ you obtain:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|f(x_n)|-|f(x_0)|}{x-x_0}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-f(x_n))-(-f(x_0))}{x_n-x_0}=\lim_{n\to\infty}-\frac{f(x_n)-f(x_0)}{x_n-x_0}=-f'(x_0)
$$
and again the last limit exists since $f(x)$ is derivable in $x_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What can you conclude from $f(x_0)\neq 0$ about the sign of $f(x)$ in the neighbourhood of $x_0$? Also use that the function is differentiable at $x_0$, which implies that it can be approximated with a linear function.